# wso2 EI/ESB setting up a antivirus possible?

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I'm working on a project that needs to subscribe to the api's of multiple social media channels, for this reason we are using wso2 EI and for security protection I would like to intercept the message contents having attachements and fire an antivirus if possible to check the contents.

I have been searching over the web and the wso2 documentation but I have very few info regarding this.Kindly suggest if there is any alternative or if possible any configuration that can be done in the esb.

Comment: There is no built-in antivirus support directly in the ESB, you will have to call the antivirus as a service or build a custom mediator

Comment: @gusto2 I was thinking of downloading the file to a temporary location and that should automaticaly fire the antivirus within the host machine

Comment: That's assumption you need to confirm. As well it would check the content for malitious payload, but not for malitious links or other attack vectors (sql injection,.)

Comment: @gusto2 Thanks for the reply.Wso2 provides an endpoint for twitter and the response I will be getting will be in json format with attachement being provided as a link.So I need to click on the link and pass the webtoken to download the attachement.